# Use JavaScript to Flag a Word From a List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use javascript to flag a word from a set list but it doesn't seem to be working. Basically I want the user to be able to type in a word and if it matches any on the list on the right it flags the word in red.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Copernicus76/rpuXW/embedded/result/

```
// Load the banned plates json data

  var platesJson = (function () {
      platesJson = null;
      $.ajax({
          'async': false,
              'global': false,
              'url': "bannedplates.json",
              'dataType': "json",
              'success': function (bannedplates) {
              platesJson = bannedplates;
          }
      });
      return platesJson;
  })();


  $(document).ready(function () {

      // Draw the list //

      $.each(platesJson, function (i) {
          $('#plate-list').append('<div class="row-' + i + '">' + platesJson[i].plate + '</div>');
      });


      // Search the banned plates //

      $('#plate-text').keyup(function () {

          var result = '';
          var plateRow = '';
          var scrollPosition;
          var searchText = $('#plate-text').val().toUpperCase();

          $.each(platesJson, function (i) {
              if (searchText == platesJson[i].plate) {
                  result = 'banned';
                  plateRow = i;
                  scrollPosition = i * 19;
              }

          });

          if (/\S/.test(searchText)) {

              if (result == 'banned') {
                  $('#plate-intro,#plate-ok').hide();
                  $('#plate-banned').show().fadeOut(1500);
                  $('#plate-text').addClass('banned');
                  $('#plate-list').animate({
                      scrollTop: scrollPosition
                  }, 1000);
                  $('#plate-list div.row-' + plateRow + '').addClass('banned');
              } else {
                  $('#plate-intro,#plate-banned').hide();
                  $('#plate-ok').show().fadeOut(1500);
                  $('#plate-text').removeClass('banned');
              }

          } else {
              $('#plate-text').val('');
              $('#plate-ok,#plate-banned').hide();
              $('#plate-intro').show();
          }

      });

  }); // end document ready
```

Comment: Start all debugging with the console (F12), and most of the time you'll spot your errors.

Comment: Please be more specific about an actual question to a problem you are having. Do not ask folks to debug code for you

Comment: Your first problem is that you're treating `$.ajax` like a synchronous function. In the context of the rest of your application `platesJson` will always be null.

Comment: My apologies and please ignore the question, because I was hoping for debugging help as I am at a loss.

Comment: @Nick's comment points out a big part of your problem. try to do a little research on javascript async programming and how to use callback functions.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Nick. I might try and avoid JS altogether and try and achieve the same, if not more simplified result using HTML5

Comment: @user2727935 -- You'll need JS, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var platesJson = (function () {
      platesJson = null;
      $.ajax({
          'async': false,
          'global': false,
          'url': "bannedplates.json",
          'dataType': "json",
          'success': function (bannedplates) {
              platesJson = bannedplates;
          }
      });
      return platesJson;
  })();
```

That's not how ajax works. The first `a` means `asynchronous`, so the success function will run whenever the response comes back. That doesn't happen immediately, it could take a few minutes or it could fail totally. The `success` method is a *callback*. That's where you want to do the magic.

```
  $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': "bannedplates.json",
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (bannedplates) {
          $.each(bannedplates, function (i) {
              $('#plate-list').append('<div class="row-' + i + '">' + bannedplates[i].plate + '</div>');
          });
          $('#plate-text').keyup(function () {
              // ...the rest of your code
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I'll give this a whirl